# Disable/Enable all Test Action controllers in JMeter test

Tags: jmeter

I have placed many DIFFERENT think times (pauses) in JMeter test. In this way I am trying to simulate real user think times, because at different places user will need different times to think/wait. Sometimes he will need 5 sec to figure out his next action, and sometimes he will need 15 sec. As I manage to check Test Action Controllers are the only way for me to do this. BUT, my problem is that while I am creating/repairing test I don't want to wait for all these pauses when I run the test just to check whether my change is passing. I want some way to easily disable all Test Action controllers during creation of test, and then when I want to run real test with bunch of concurrent threads then just to easily enable all pauses.

Comment: any feedback on answer, if it"s ok you should accept it and upvote so that it's useful to others ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Test Actions because I did not understand how timers are working. I thought they are always applied to all samplers (which is not true). I can easily accomplish what I want with constant timer. So using test actions wasn't a must. I will just add constant timer to specific sampler and it will be applied only to this sampler. Sorry if I made confusion with a way I asked the question :(

Answer (score 3):

You first modify your Test Action this way:

- Set sleep to 0
- Add as a child to each one a Timer with pause you want

Then
There is a menu called Start no pause in the GUI which is here exactly for this need:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter-new-gui-features-to-increase-your-productivity/

There is also since 3.0 a "Validation Mode" that you can acces by right click on Thread Group and select validate

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: start no pause doesn't have effect on test action controllers. It affects only timers (I think it affects all of them but not 100% sure)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way of doing it is running your test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool. It has possibility to enable/disable Test Elements basing on their names so you will be able to switch your Test Actions samplers on and off.

See [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) chapter for more details.

Example Taurus YAML config to disable Test Action samplers. Save it as i.e. `test.yml` in the same folder your .jmx script lives

```
---
scenarios:
  modification_example:
    script: test.jmx   # Name of your original JMeter test script
    modifications:
        disable:       # Names of the tree elements to disable
        - Test Action
execution:
- scenario: modification_example
```

Running `bzt test.yml -gui` command will open JMeter GUI with modifications applied.

Taurus entry level information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

---

Don't waste your time trying "Run no pauses" and "Validate" options, the guy doesn't seem to know how does JMeter work.

---

All right, here's JMeter-only solution via [Beanshell Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

```
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
import org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode;
import org.apache.jmeter.sampler.TestAction;              

 GuiPackage guiInstance = GuiPackage.getInstance();
 guiInstance.getTreeModel().getTestPlan();
 List testactionlist = guiInstance.getTreeModel().getNodesOfType(TestAction.class);
 for (Object testAction : testactionlist) {
     JMeterTreeNode testActionSampler = (JMeterTreeNode) testAction;
     testActionSampler.setEnabled(false);
 }
```

Comment: thanks man for suggesting this tool. for now will stick to Jmeter because I am in rush to finish some tests for company. at some point will check Taurus. and yes I know "start no pause" will not help for test actions.

Comment: I uodated my answer

Comment: Same crap as before

Answer (score -2):

If you open the test in any text editor you will see all the test actions like 

you can easyly find & replace all " testname="Test Action" **enabled="true"** " to **enabled="false"**

Comment: This does not seem to be a viable solution although it works for you.